# Find $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + ik}$ using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Calculate using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem: $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + ik}$$

I'm not sure how should I approach that. I think I should use the inequality
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{n^2 + ik} \right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} $$
and use the latter as the 'dominating' function. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The complex numbers aren’t an ordered field!

Comment: The dominating function is just right, though.

Comment: @Fakemistake Sorry, I meant to use absolute value there. I think it should work now.

Comment: You have almost finished the proof of the fact that the limit is $0$. Just apply DCT.

Answer (score 1):

With the counting measure on $\mathbb N$, you have the functions $f_k(n) = \frac 1{n^2+ik} : \mathbb N \to \mathbb C$. The fact that $f_k$ are non-negative and pointwise bounded by the integrable series $\frac 1{n^2}$, shows that each $f_k$ is integrable.

Furthermore, note that for each $n$, we have pointwise $f_k(n) \to 0$, because the denominator keeps increasing in absolute value to infinity, hence the fraction decreases in absolute value to zero.

Therefore, $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k = 0$ as a function on $\mathbb N$. The bounding by an integrable series shows that the Dominated Convergence Theorem can be applied, showing that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_k(n) = 0$.